# Add axis to ggplot facet_wrap histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-wrap

I'm trying to create a series of histograms with the same range on the axis and crucially axis that lie at zero intercepts for both `x` and `y`

```
mydat1 <- mydat + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5) + facet_wrap(~V2, scales = "free") + theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.05), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.05)) + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

adding `+ ylim` and `xlim` to try and constrain the axis to the same ranges doesnt appear to work.

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

[This is what I want to produce but I need `y` to range from 0-15 and `x` from 0-400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcPcG.jpg)

Comment: please add `dput(mydat)` to make your code reproducible. `scales = "free" `might not be what you want to do

Comment: scales =  free seems to be the only way to get an axis on each individual chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))
```

and

```
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 400))
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Mario's solution worked when combined with the epand fucntion i.e.

```
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,400)
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,15)
```